# how to create an irregular shaped button in iphone/ipad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, button

I am creating a pie chart in which each section is a separate button with background image and denotes an individual method, but uibutton has a rectangular shape and all the buttons overlap.

I want to select a section(button) (i.e the button shape should be the image's shape not the default rectangular button) without disturbing the adjacent sections(buttons)...

eg: consider an pie chart with 8 sectors denoted by 8 buttons from 1 to 8,the buttons have background images of sectored shape,if a user taps anywhere on 1st sector(button) then any other sector(button) should not be clicked...

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the whole pie chart.

Get the coordinates of the tap within the chart, and use mathematics to determine which slice the tap is on.

Answer (score 0):

if your using in interface builder,Just change your button type into custom and assign yur image to the button.in coding just assign a customised button

Comment: a customised button has a rectangular area of selection...it is not exactly the image...